# Achieving Pixel-Perfect Display in Unity 2D Game with 32x32 Pixel Art Animations

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, pixel, 2d-games

I am relatively new to game development and currently working on a 2D project in Unity using C# with pixel art animations (32x32px sprites). Despite setting up the project with specific configurations, I have encountered challenges in achieving pixel-perfect display during transformations like rotation, scaling, and camera zoom.

### Problem Description:

1. **Independently Rescaling, Rotating, and Zooming:** In 2D Unity C# games using pixel art sprites, is it considered good practice to independently rescale, rotate, or zoom in on objects? These transformations seem to compromise pixel art aesthetics unless generated or animated frame by frame.
2. **Pixel Art Rotation Distortion:** Rotating a pixel art image in Unity causes pixel distortion. For example, rotating a sprite by 45 degrees makes separate pixel squares and lines composed of pixels look like a correct diagonal, while at the same scale, the horizontal position of the image's pixel represents a visible square. How can I achieve pixel-perfect rotation without distorting the intended pixel art aesthetics?

[image]

3. **Handling Real Pixel Art Sprites:** I need to use real pixel art sprites, where characters are 32x32px and bigger with a similar scale. How can I correctly process existing pixel art, maybe just changing the scale for sprites? Should I use anisotropic texture instead of 'disabling' as in my setup? What example shader should I use to make it look like real pixel art?
4. **Optimal Sizes and Scaling:** My goal is to find optimal sizes considering both PC and Mobile devices. The current setup with 'Pixel Perfect Camera' disables scale and zoom, but the pixel size is too small. How can I set up my game to make it look real and sharp with an accent on small pixels while considering animations that provide small details close to 16x16px games design but with 32px consistency?

### Current Setup:

#### Project Settings 'Quality':

- Anisotropic Textures: Disabled
- Anti Aliasing: Disabled

#### Resolution:

- Main Camera: Orthographic

#### Camera:

- Solid Color

#### gameObject:

- Scale: X 1, Y 1, Z 1

#### Game:

- 800x450 (instead of Free Aspect)

#### Inspector:

- Texture is default Sprite (2D and UI)
- Pixel Per Unit: 32
- Sprite Mode: Multipal
- Filter Mode: (no filter)
- Max Size: 4096
- Compression: None

#### CinemachineBrain (CinemachineVirtualCamera):

- Cinemachine Pixel Perfect (Script)
- Virtual Camera Ortho Size: 3.2.

#### 'Pixel Perfect Camera':

- Assets Pixels Per Unit: 32
- Reference Resolution X 800 Y 450
- Pixel Snapping: Checked

Maybe I can use [pixel-shader](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/fullscreen-camera-effects/pixelation-65554) for 32x32px image, but it is not quite clear how it will affect horizontal pixels.

I appreciate any guidance on optimizing my setup and achieving pixel-perfect display in a 2D pixel art game.

Thank you!

Comment: According to the Pixel Perfect Camera docs, they suggest setting the Assets Pixels Per Unit to the same as all your sprites.  `Asset Pixels Per Unit -
This value is the amount of pixels that make up one unit of the Scene. Match this value to the Pixels Per Unit values of all Sprites within the Scene`.  Set that to 32, hopefully that is all thats needed.  [Pixel Perfect Camera Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.pixel-perfect@1.0/manual/index.html)

Comment: @hijinxbassist Hello. Thank you for answer, but using 'Pixel Perfect Camera' docs setting shows single pixel only with 'Scale 5x' in 'Game' view. If I make objects a bit larger to show pixels closer, rescaling 'Field of view', then diagonally aligned pixel of my sprite consist of 9 horizontal pixels. Rescaling animation  still produces artefacts with diagonal position of rotated image pixel.